# Checking if session variable is set or not in django

Tags: python, django, session

I need to check if the session is set or not ... I followed some solutions from stackoverflow but still problem exists

```
if request.session.get('orderId',None):
    request.session['orderId']=ts
    orderId=request.session['orderId']
else:
    orderId=request.session['orderId']
```

It is saying keyError at orderId in line just below else:

Answer (score 3):

your conditional is inverted. Try inverting like:

```
if not request.session.get('orderId', None):
    request.session['orderId'] = ts
    orderId = request.session['orderId']
else:
    orderId = request.session['orderId']
```

`.get('orderId', None)` will return `None` and the 
`if not request.session.get('orderId', None)` will direct you to populate the session, which (probably) is what you wanted.

a better way can be

```
orderId = request.session.setdefault('orderId', ts)
```

this will give you `orderId` from the session if exists, otherwise it will populate the session with `ts` and return you that.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of the get method is to keep the code clean. This should work:

```
orderId = request.session.get('orderId',ts)
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I missed this:

```
orderId = request.session.get('orderId',ts)
request.session['orderId']=ts
```

There is no need for if and else...

Comment: `ts` only gets assigned to `request.session` when the value of `orderId` is `None`(or evaluated to `True` in OP's current logic)